# Page option under create menu in sites is not available in my local instance

Tags: aem

In my local instance of AEM 6.4, i'm not able to see 'page' option under create menu in sites.
i have created an editable template and enabled it.
what am i missing here ?

I have verified in Vanilla instance also, i don't see this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first create the project structure using the archetype project like maven archetype 13, refer this link for archetype 13, https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/maven_arch13.html

This archetype also creates the basic content of a website with root page (example in this case: AEMTraining) and few language pages. Once you have created the project structure and your own global page is available under sites, click on the rootpage. Now, you can see the Page option under create, so you can use your editable template to create
your own pages. (Check the image)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. One last question, usually during initial project creation do we create this root page manually or using our project base template?

Comment: @rajumuddana In previous versions of AEM, we used to create the root page using a template, but now I suggest to create the root page using the **Maven Archetype** project (_where the root page gets created automatically_).
Instead of using the Base page template to create pages, **create the templates for different pages** like (Language, Home etc based on your requirement of pages) which extends the base page template.
Once the root page is created, you can create pages using your own templates under root page. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You ll need to create the root page for your site and add the property cq:allowedTemplates. Only then create page shows for the permitted templates.